# Error: No selenium server jar found at "Location"

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-code, automation, protractor, serenity-js

**I am facing following issue :**

> Error: No selenium server jar found at
>   C:\ui-automation\serenity-1.0\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar.

When I am trying to run my test using protractor using following command:

```
protractor .\protractor.conf.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This error comes into picture in two scenario :*

**1. selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar does not exist :**

> In your project's
> "**node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium**"
> location.

To Resolve this you have to run following command :

```
webdriver-manager update
```

**2. selenium-server-standalone exists with different version :**

In this scenario you have to download the required selenium-server-standalone jar as follow :

> `webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone "specific_version"`

Example :

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone 3.0.1
```

OR

```
node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone 3.0.1
```